# React axios put request returns error 500

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch, put

```
axios.put('http://1.1.1.1:1010/api/data', {
    data: {
        ip: '123123',
        smth: true
    },
    headers: {
        'content-type': "application/json ",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
})
```

I recieved

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

Get request works fine. I tryed without any success:

```
headers: {
    'content-type': "application/json ",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
},

data: {
    ip: '123123',
    dhcp: true
},
withCredentials: true,
crossdomain: true,
proxy: {
    host: 'http://1.1.1.1',
    port: 1010
},
validateStatus: (status) => {
    return true; 
},
```

In the backend error on the last line::

```
json_data = request.get_json(force=True)
accountGuid = 'DummyAccount'
pdict = json_data[self.tableName]
```

Help me please. I don't understood what I have to do

Comment: Since you are getting 500 (Internal Server Error) I guess you might have some error in your Backend code. Could you show us that? You are not getting "Not found" or "Bad request" which indicates that your request might be valid.

Comment: @Kamelkent I got code from backend developer, can't sent to you another. Maybe you have any assumptions about backend error. And you sure that my request valid?

Comment: Usually you want the url to contain the id of the item you want to update, which you don't have, but that would probably get you a 404 and not 500. You could try ''http://1.1.1.1:1010/api/data/123123''

When you do your Get call you have a proxy configured as well as withCredentials and crossdomain, you don't need that for Put as well?

Do you get any more information about the error in the Network tab in your browser? You might get an inner exception that tells you something.

Is it Put you want to do? If you want to create a new item you might use Post instead.

Comment: What does it display when you update your catch block like this: .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response);
})

Comment: @SuleymanSah `Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)`

Comment: @Kamelkent http://skrinshoter.ru/i/101219/bIPfpxrl.png and http://skrinshoter.ru/i/101219/8ItDYbkz.png

Comment: @ttard I think you need to get in touch with your backend developer. I cannot see anything wrong with your request based on the information you've given us. At least ask him/her to guide you to the logs to see what goes wrong. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm not sure what the logic is behind this but it recently happened to me.
I had a put request that was giving me 500 internal server error but on postman the same request would work fine.

Here is what fixed the issue.
axios has two ways of sending request.

```
axios.put(url,body,config);
```

and

```
axios(request object);
```

I am sharing my code. May be it helps you as well.

The request was failing at this code.

```
const { data } = await axios.put(`trainer-schedule/cancel-appointment-student/${id}`, null, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_token'),
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        }
    });
```

I just changed it to other way and it started working.

```
const { data } = await axios({
        url: `trainer-schedule/cancel-appointment-student/${id}`,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_token'),
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        method: 'put'
    });
```

> My envoirenment is react-native, backend express js.

I would recommend to always test your requests on postman. It is the best tool out there to test apis. but what happened to me is a very rare case.

I hope it helps you.